# unsatisfied or ambiguous dependencies for injection point on a class which has a specific constructor

Tags: constructor, cdi, inject

I have a question related to CDI warning unsatisfied or ambiguous dependencies for injection point.

The piece of code:

```
@Named(value = "LoginView")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginView implements Serialization {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private  UserContext userContext;

}
```

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserContext implements Serialization {

    public UserContext(String app, String prod, List<String>prodLines) {
        this.app=app;
        this.prod=prod;
        this.prodLines = prodLines;
    }
}
```

I get:

> org.weld.exceptions.DeploymentExceptions: unsatisfied dependencies for type[UserContext] with qualifiers[@Inject] injection point.

If I try to remove `@Inject` the deployment issue is fixed but the usercontext object is null so throws `NullPointerException`. I am not using EJB so cannot use `@EJB` instead of `@Inject`.

Comment: Check for any previous errors. I'd suspect that CDI can't construct the `UserContext` due to missing information on the constructor or the missing no-arg constructor.

Comment: Possible problem is that `UserContext` couldn't be instantiated since it has no no-arguments constructor. You need to either tell the DI framework what constructor arguments to use or create a no-argument constructor and inject the three parameters using `@Inject` or through setters.

Comment: @JiriTousek  Good Point. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by creating a no-argument constructor in UserContext. There was a parameterized constructor created so the CDI injection could not call the default constructor. We have explicitly created a default no-argmument constructor therefore CDI injection worked. 
Created beans.xml for Fixing unsatisfied and ambiguous dependencies and added to META-INF. If you have explicitly enable an @Alternative bean that implements the bean type and has the appropriate qualifier types, using beans.xml.